# Insert '\x' in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, crc16

I am trying to use crcmod correctly but I have problem:
For example I would like to transform the string `"1234567809"` into the bytes `b'\x12\x34\x56\x78\x09'` in order to obtain the correct crc16 modbus code.

```
import crcmod

crc16 = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x18005, rev=True, initCrc=0xffff)
for i in range(len(a)//2):
    a = a[:(i*4)] + r"\x" + a[i*4:]
```

The problem is that `r"\x"` inserts `'\\x'`, not `'\x'`,
and of course `'\x'` returns an error.

```
a.encode("utf-8")
```

of course returns `b'\\x12\\x34\\x56\\x78\\x09'`.

That is the result with `\\x`:

```
hex(crc16(a.encode("utf-8")))
'0x68b7'
```

That is the result I expected:

```
hex(crc16(b'\x12\x34\x56\x78\x09'))
'0x2590'
```

Comment: `r"\x"` *does* insert the two characters `\x`, but when it is printed to the terminal, the character ```\``` is sometimes shown as ```\\```.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly convert a string: `'1234567809'` to the bytes you want:

```py
source = '1234567809'
a = bytes.fromhex(source)
```

Now the crc should work:

```py
hex(crc16(a))
```